# Calculate shortest distance between many points with MySQL spatial (by proceeding the rows in the loop?)

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, geospatial, geocoding

**I) PROBLEM**

Let’s say there are 4 tables:

**Table: assignment_has_place**

```
| assignment_id | place_id |
|---------------|----------|
| 1             | 1        |
| 2             | 4        |
| 2             | 5        |
```

**Table: agent_has_place**

```
| agent_id | place_id |
|----------|----------|
| 1        | 2        |
| 2        | 1        |
| 1        | 3        |
| 1        | 4        |
| 3        | 4        |
| 3        | 6        |
```

**Table: assignment_has_agent**

```
| assignment_id | agent_id |
|---------------|----------|
| 1             | 1        |
| 1             | 2        |
| 2             | 3        |
```

**Table: place** (test data)

```
| Place_id | Name        | Geodata                 |
|----------|-------------|-------------------------|
| 1        | New-York    | POINT(-74.0072 40.7131) |
| 2        | Los Angeles | POINT(-118.244 34.0522) |
| 3        | Boston      | POINT(-71.0589 42.3601) |
| 4        | Chicago     | POINT(-87.6298 41.8781) |
| 5        | Dallas      | POINT(-96.797 32.7767)  |
| 6        | Austin      | POINT(-97.7431 30.2672) |
```

So, an assignment can have many places, an agent can have many (personal) places (e.g. home, work, parent home, etc…) and an assignment can have many agents.

I study the relationship between the places of agents assignments and the agents (personal) places. Then, **I want to know the shortest distance between each agents assignment place and all of his (personal) places**. (In another word, I want to find the nearest agent (personal) place for each his assignment place and to know the distance between them).

**II) CURRENT QUERY**

```
SELECT
    assignment_has_agent.agent_id AS agent,
    place.place_id AS place_of_assignment,

-- BEGIN. Calculate distance between agents places and agents places of assignment
    ST_Distance_Sphere(place.geodata, -- This is a geodata about a place of assignment

        -- BEGIN. Select geodata for all agents places
        (SELECT
            place.geodata -- This is a geodata about an agents place
        FROM
            place
        INNER JOIN agent_has_place -- Get geodata about agents place
        ON agent_has_place.place_id = place.place_id
        WHERE agent_has_place.agent_id = assignment_has_agent.agent_id
        LIMIT 1 -- Here the problem!!! Without LIMIT Mysql error "Subquery returns more than 1 row"
        )
        -- END. Select geodata for all agents places
    ) 
    AS shortest_distance
-- END. Calculate distance between agents places and agents places of assignment

    FROM
        assignment_has_place 
    LEFT JOIN assignment_has_agent -- Make a link between assignment and agent
        ON assignment_has_agent.assignment_id = assignment_has_place.assignment_id  
    LEFT JOIN place -- Get a geodata about the place of assignment
        ON place.place_id = assignment_has_place.place_id

    GROUP BY assignment_has_agent.agent_id, place.place_id
```

**III) CURRENT RESULT**

```
| agent | place_of_assignment | shortest_distance  |
|-------|---------------------|--------------------|
| 1     | 1                   | 3935659.762302256  | -- Note: New-York<>Los Angeles
| 2     | 1                   | 0                  | -- Note: New-York<>New-York
| 3     | 4                   | 0                  | -- Note: Chicago<>Chicago
| 3     | 5                   | 1294952.4320354236 | -- Note: Dallas<>Chicago
```

**In my current query I have to add *LIMIT 1*, otherwise I have mysql error “Subquery returns more than 1 row”. (See code above.)** It is  because the agent can have many (personal) places.
So this result is incorrect, because it takes only the first row among all agents (personal) places.

**IV) EXPECTED RESULT**

```
| agent | place_of_assignment | shortest_distance  |
|-------|---------------------|--------------------|
| 1     | 1                   | 306167.42792567355 | -- Note: New-York<>Boston
| 2     | 1                   | 0                  | -- Note: New-York<>New-York
| 3     | 4                   | 0                  | -- Note: Chicago<>Chicago
| 3     | 5                   | 293094.4286555507  | -- Note: Dallas<>Austin
```

**I need to calculate the distance between all places of assignment and all agents (personal) places and then choose the shortest (minimal) distance.**

**V) QUESTION(S)**

How to obtain the expected result? I suppose it is not too hard to choose shortest distance with MIN()?
But how I can proceed the every row of agent (personal) places? Do I have to use a loop (cursor??? Can I use it here?) or there is any other (simpler) way to do this?

Many thanks for any advice!

**SEE DEMO [HERE](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jcFwHJeWtJ84BL2rqGen6v/0)**

Comment: SQL isn't best optimized for this. It might be worth exploring further afield.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. All my data in mysql for now and any solution (not necessarily optimized) with mysql will suit me.

Comment: It's fine that the data is in MySQL. I'm talking about how that data is processed. Your problem is (I think) n-p complete; books have been written on the implications of this.

Comment: Beyond the complexity theory, my problem is the absence of "for each" loop in sql, and how to workarounds this.